# jenkinsfile - check if method is defined

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, dsl

I am trying to execute a stage only if a function exists:

```
if (binding.variables.containsKey(functionName)){
    stage ("execute") {
      script{
        "${functionName}"(config)
      }
    }
  }
```

the problem is that binding.variables return only variables (**I should have guessed that**). is there a way to check if a function is defined?

Comment: There is a way to check if a method is defined (unsure about function), but not a way to execute a stage only if it exists in declarative syntax. Are you using scripted or declarative? Is it ok to check method existence instead of function existence?

Comment: I am using declarative. but the function is to be execute in a script{} closure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MethodNotFound is a checked Exception in the Exception Hierarchy and hard to capture in groovy or Java flow with `try..catch` block, so it hard to achieve your goal

[image]

If the method or DSL is not defined in Jenkins, Jenkins will through an exception while parsing the scripted or declarative pipeline - In that case, I don't think you can capture it ever